# ActionMailer's mail method works on Heroku but not on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error seems to be very non-descriptive:

```
failed with ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message
```

I think this is not the real problem since I've tried specifying "from" even though I set a default.  Also, the code is identical for localhost and Heroku...

```
def invite_dealer(auction, name, email, dealer)
  return false if dealer.bids.where("auction_id = ?", auction.id).present?
  @name = name  #used on template
  @email = email  
  @auction = auction  #this too
  mail(:to => @email, :subject => "New Auction - #{auction.car.name}", :from => "realaddressishereonmymachine@ourdomain.com")
end
```

Comment: PS All of the other mail delays I'm using work fine on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `failed with ArgumentError: A sender (Return-Path, Sender or From) required to send a message` can occur if `mail` method was not invoked from `invite_dealer` method.

So putting conditional `return` into `invite_dealer` method before call to `mail` method is bad idea.

Comment: This is exactly the problem, you cannot `return` from a mail method to short-circuit the delivery. You need to put the logic to not invoke the mailer outside the mailer in question.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to development.rb seems to have fixed it - strange all the other mail methods were working:

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'localhost:3000'
```